# Assigning values to arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays

I'm a bit curious about why does this work:

```
$arr1[] = $arr2[] = $value;
```

If I'm correct, first the value is pushed to the end of arr2. Then `$arr2[]` pushed to the end of `$arr1`. This is where I'm confused. If I do it separately like:

```
$var = $arr2[];
```

I get "Fatal error: Cannot use [] for reading..."

But how come `[]` works for reading when I'm doing multiple assignments in the same statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $var is not an array. To make $var an array:

```
$var = array();
```

or,

```
$var = $arr2;
```

Comment: sorry, but this doesn't answer the question. PHP's loose typing allows the assignment from any value to any variable, regardless what type that variable was before. The error occurs because it is not possible to **read** from an array with `[]`, but on the other hand it is allowed to **write** to an array with `[]`

Answer (score 2):

> If I'm correct, first the value is pushed to the end of `$arr2`. Then
>   `$arr2[]` pushed to the end of `$arr1`.

That's not correct. What happens is that `$value` is pushed to the end of both arrays, one at a time. The phrase "`$arr2[]` is pushed" is meaningless because the expression `$arr2[]` is not valid in a read context (i.e. it does not "have a value"), which is exactly what the error message you got in your second attempt says.

> But how come [] works for reading when I'm doing multiple assignments
>   in the same statement?

Chaining the assignment operator in PHP does not work quite as it does in certain other languages. In particular,

```
$x = $y = (expr);
```

is treated in the same way as if you had written

```
// the purpose of $temp is to prevent (expr) from being evaluated twice,
// because evaluating it might have side effects (e.g. think $i++)
$temp = (expr);
$x = $temp;
$y = $temp;
```

That is, `$arr1[]` is not being assigned the value `$arr2[]` but rather `$value` directly because the assignment operator evaluates to its right-hand-side operand.

Answer (score 1):

This suggestion is wrong:

> Then $arr2[] pushed to the end of $arr1.

From the manual:

> The value of an assignment expression is the value assigned. That is,
>   the value of "$a = 3" is 3. This allows you to do some tricky things...

So, first assignment operator `$arr2[] = $value` returns value of $value, which can be assigned further.

Answer (score 0):

`But how come [] works for reading when I'm doing multiple assignments in the same statement?`

it doesnt.

try var dumping it

```
$a = array();
var_dump ($a[] = 2);
```

which returns

```
int(2)
```

That value is then passed to the second so `$b = $a = 2`

does `$a=2`, which returns 2, then  assigns that value to `$b[]`

```
var_dump($a[]);
```

on the other hand doesnt make sense as `var_dump($a[])` doesnt exist, it can only be used for writing to an array

Answer (score -1):

`$arr1[] = $arr2[] = $value;` this works because you are first assigning a variable or string to an array `$arr2[]` and then again assiging that array to another array `$arr1[]`.
But in case `$var = $arr2[];` you are assing array to a normal variable which is **not permitted**.

For doing this you need to make $var as an array as `$var = array();`

Comment: -1 because it's not assigning an array to another array. Also, "not permitted" is patently false information. Of course it is permitted, the actual problem is fully explained by the error message: `$arr[]` cannot be used in a read context.